# How to let the user change the width of a frame

Tags: qt4, pyqt4

My Qt4 application has basically two frames, each displaying more or less independent content.  The user should be able to make one frame smaller (and the other one bigger)

Much like the behavior in a QTableView where a user can make one column smaller or bigger.

Is there a Qt widget supporting this? If not, any advice on how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look into `QtGui.QSplitter` (http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsplitter.html). For example

```
# Add horizontal splitter 
horizontalSplitter = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)

# Add two widgets
horizontalSplitter.addWidget(widget1)
horizontalSplitter.addWidget(widget2)
```

You get a horizontal splitter that is drag-able. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect! This was indeed what I was looking for. Thanks!